# Schemaless mode in solr while indexing from a database

Tags: solr, schemaless

I am trying to index some data from the database and I want to opt for schemaless mode. I did the basic database connection in the filesystem and no other settings done. 
Now, when I index, I can see the documents indexed but when I try to query, I don't see any dynamic fields there. 
Has anyone dealt with the same scenario and can help me on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataImportHandler and want dynamic schema, you need to explicitly declare the database->Solr field mapping in your data definition file.

Otherwise, DIH looks at schema definition to figure out what fields to copy to avoid creating fields you may not want. Which causes catch-22 if you have not declared them yet.

Try creating an explicit definition for one or two fields and see if reindexing makes them appear.